# Parse Pointer object in PHP using Object ID

Tags: php, parse-platform

How can I create a Parse Pointer object using the object ID? I have tried the below and several variations with no success.

```
$obj = new ParseObject("App");
$obj->setAssociativeArray('__type' => 'Pointer', 'className' => 'App', 'objectId' => 'cZtFWprxBe');
```

Answer (score 1):

From the source code given in 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php

you can create pointers using either

$p = ParseObject::create($className, $objectId , $isPointer);

or

$p = new ParseObject($className, $objectId , $isPointer);

Set the third argument $isPointer to true when creating a pointer to an object.